# List refresh every time when came back from previous screen in tab layout view pager listing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, tabs, android-viewpager, onresume

To detect which fragment is currently visible in ViewPager. Now we just use onResume and onPause methods instead of getUserVisibleHint() i.e. deprecated.
So for this we call Api in on Resume method now

My issue is that now when i click on any item of list and coming back from screen onResume gets called again and list refreshed every time when i came back from previous screen

How to prevent this refreshing of list every time?

Comment: Which design patterns you use? if you use view model and Mutable live data, then it will not refresh your list if object is already initialized.

Comment: Why are you, calling API requests in `onResume()`, instead you can do that in their respective `viewModels`. Which won't refresh your fragments.